# Thread pool using boost::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I would like to make a portable thread pool using `boost::thread`. Some one could tell me to look at `boost::thread_group` and `boost::asio`. I know, but I am not really familiar with these things so I don't know if they are suitable for my purpose.

Please give me comments on what I supposed to do here.

JobItem and JobQueue:

```
class JobItem
{
private:
    uint32_t        job_type_;      //!< Job type
    char*           job_ptr_;       //!< Pointer to job content
// ...
};

class JobQueue
{
private:
    queue<JobItem*>                 job_queue_;
public:
    // Definitely I need to use mutex and condition variable here
    JobItem* pick();
    void push(JobItem* job_item);
};
```

JobWorker (worker thread):

```
class JobWorker
{
private:
    JobQueue* shared_job_queue_;
    boost::thread the_thread_;

public:
    JobWorker(JobQueue* shared_queue) : shared_job_queue_(shared_queue);

    // exec_job will be overridden by concrete subclasses
    virtual void exec_job(JobItem* job_item) = 0;
    void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            JobItem* job = shared_job_queue_->pick();
            exec_job(job);
            delete job;
        }
    }
    void start()
    {
        the_thread_ = boost::thread(boost::bind(&JobWorker::run, this));
    }
    void stop()
    {
        the_thread_.join();
    }
};
```

Concrete JobWorker subclasses:

```
class Task_1_Worker : public JobWorker
{
    // override exec_job
    void exec_job(JobItem* job)
    {
        // Process job item here
    }
}

class Task_2_Worker : public JobWorker
{
    // override exec_job
    void exec_job(JobItem* job)
    {
        // Process job item here
    }
}
```

Now, WorkerPool with template:

```
template <class JobWorkerT>
class WorkerPool
{
private:
    JobQueue shared_job_queue_;
    list<JobWorkerT> job_workers_;

public:
    WorkerPool(const int num_threads);
    ~WorkerPool(void) {};

    void push(JobItem* job)
    {
        shared_job_queue_.push(job);
    }
    void start();
    void stop();
};

template <class JobWorkerT>
WorkerPool<JobWorkerT>::WorkerPool(const int num_threads)
{
    for(int i=0; i<num_threads; i++)
    {
        JobWorkerT job_worker(&shared_job_queue_);
        job_workers_.push_back(job_worker);
    }
}

template <class JobWorkerT>
void WorkerPool<JobWorkerT>::start()
{
    for(std::list<JobWorkerT>::iterator iter = job_workers_.begin(); iter != job_workers_.end(); iter++)
    {
        ((JobWorkerT)(*iter)).start();
    }
}

template <class JobWorkerT>
void WorkerPool<JobWorkerT>::stop()
{
    for(std::list<JobWorkerT>::iterator iter = job_workers_.begin(); iter != job_workers_.end(); iter++)
    {
        ((JobWorkerT)(*iter)).stop();
    }
}
```

main()

```
int main()
{
    WorkerPool<Task_1_Worker>* task1_grp = new WorkerPool<Task_1_Worker>();
    WorkerPool<Task_2_Worker>* task2_grp = new WorkerPool<Task_2_Worker>();

    task1_grp->start();
    task2_grp->start();

    // Producers should call task1_grp.push(JobItem*) or task2_grp.push(JobItem*) to dispatch new jobs to thread pools
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Design

Not sure why you have a virtual function on the worker?

```
virtual void exec_job(JobItem* job_item) = 0;
```

The worker is simple he picks up jobs and then does them. What the job is defines what work should be done. So I would have put the virtual function that defines the work on the JobItem.

The `run()` function of the worker is then simply.

```
void run()
{
    // You want some way for the thread to eventually exit.
    // You can make that happen by letting the queue return
    // a null object when the object is being shut down.
    JobItem* job;
    while(job = shared_job_queue_->pick())
    {
        job->do();
        delete job;
    }
}
```

### Code Review

#### Prefer not to use pointers.

Pointers don't have the concept of ownership semantics. So we don't know who is responsible for deleting them. Use a type that conveys ownership semantics so the person reading the code understands the semantics.

```
 JobQueue* shared_job_queue_;
```

You always need a job queue. So this can never be `nullptr`. So rather than a pointer a better choice would have been a reference. Also a reference implies there is no ownership of the object so you are not supposed to delete it.

```
class JobWorker
{
private:
    JobQueue& shared_job_queue_;    
public:
    JobWorker(JobQueue& shared_queue)
        : shared_job_queue_(shared_queue)
    {}
```

Again in the `JobQueue`. You push and pop pointers. So there is no concept of ownership.

```
class JobQueue
{
private:
    queue<JobItem*>                 job_queue_;
public:
    // Definitely I need to use mutex and condition variable here
    JobItem* pick();
    void push(JobItem* job_item);
};
```

As a user of this class I could easily accidently pass the address of a Job object that is actual an automatic variable. Unless I read the code it is not obvious that the code will blow up. Even worse the code may not blow up for a while since the pointer is not deleted until after the work has been done.

In this case I would use a smart pointer. The obvious one is `std::unique_ptr`. When you use this as a parameter you are indicating that you are accepting ownership of the object.

```
class JobQueue
{
private:
    // You are maintaining a queue of owned pointers.
    // You will take responsibility for deleting them when this
    // object is destroyed.
    queue<std::unique_ptr<JobItem>>      job_queue_;
public:
    // This method returns a pointer.
    // More importantly it is returning ownership of the pointer to
    // you uniquely so you are the sole owner of the pointer and the
    // JobQueue is no longer retaining any pointers to this object.
    std::unique_ptr<JobItem> pick();


    // This method accepts a unique_ptr.
    // Because it accepts the unique_ptr by value you are loosing
    // ownership. Once this method is called you will no longer own
    // the object it will be gone from the object you passed.
    void push(std::unique_ptr<JobItem> job_item);
};
```

### Use modern C++

Its 2016. C++11 has been out for 5 years. C++14 has been out for two years. Both have `std::thread` and the associated parallel libraries.

Comment: Actually, in this design, JobItem is just a data piece. Based on job type, exec_job will properly manipulate on the data. Also, due to license, I am using VC++ 2008, so there is no way for me to target to C++11 or later. I think boost libraries might help.

Comment: I am saying that `JobItem` is a better place to put your virtual function. The job should know how to execute itself. This is the open/closed principle. Now when you have to add new functionality you have to have a different worker type which means re-compiling the application. By makeing the `JobItem` have the virtual function a new lib can add a different work type without having to re-build the worker type.

Comment: After thinking a lot of `virtual JobItem::execute()` I decided to go on the way you pointed out. Thank you very much!